# friends or competition for work

Tags: job-search, job, education

I am in doubt if I should share new academic opportunities, studies, etc with college's friends, because they will may be my future competition for a job and they may get the job thanks to the help I gave to them. What do you guys think about this. Am I being selfish?

Comment: Of course, they might give you help as well. That is partly what friends are for...

Comment: They are friends!!! Of course you should! Friendship should always be higher valued than money, jobs,... If they are real friends, you might be both happy for the other if they get an opportunity or job.

Comment: Good karma has a higher long-term value than nearly anything else in life. That includes monetary value.

Answer (score 7):

Yes - it's not only good practice to share new information about career opportunities or research findings with your friends, but that's one way to build a healthy network of collaborators and a healthy community. Even if there's a chance that a friend gets a job you were hoping for, ideally they remain your friend and you can learn from their experience second-hand.

It's also good practice to share new discoveries with people who *aren't* explicitly your friends, both from the perspective of [open science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_science) and because, well, you're probably not going to apply for every job you see or write every paper you can conceive.